# .NET 6 API: Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing from response header

Tags: .net, azure, api, cors

I have a .NET 6 web API which is registered on the Azure AD as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration).
I have also [registered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-registration) a web app that calls my API and handles the authentication. I can use that to get the token and then use it in Postman to send requests to my API.

Now there is a React app (developed by another team) that should be the frontend of my API.
I'm trying to setup the whole application locally, my API is listening on localhost:5220 while the React app is running on localhost:3001.
When I try to send a request I get the following error: [image]

The error message:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5220/api/job/all' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> GET http://localhost:5220/api/job/all net::ERR_FAILED 307

These are my headers:

[image]

And here is part of my Program.cs:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3001").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I see that this is the required order of the middlewares, if I remove the `UseHttpsRedirection` or put it after `UseCors` I get a 401 error, but then the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header appears in the response. I've installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors NuGet package but it's grayed out.

This is my applicationUrl from launchSettings.json:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7220;http://localhost:5220"
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I configure my API to send the correct headers back? Why doesn't my code use the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` directive?

EDIT: Turned out, the frontend app wasn't sending the access_token, but now it's updated so I receive the token with every request (and the token is working in Postman) but I still face the same issues as described above. When I remove the HttpsRedirection and the localhost:7220 from the launchSettings I still get the 401 Unauthorized error, but I also get this message in the log:

> [2023-01-19 13:02:24.112 +02:00  INF]  Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
>
> DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
>
> ScopeAuthorizationRequirement:Scope=
>
> [2023-01-19 13:02:24.114 +02:00  INF]  AuthenticationScheme: Bearer
> was challenged.

Can someone tell me why isn't this working?

Comment: Because the `http://localhost:5220/api/job/all` resource responds with a cross-origin redirect (note that the ports are different), the target of that redirect (`http://localhost:7220/api/job/all`) would need to be configured for CORS and allow origin `http://localhost:3001` for the CORS check to be successful.

Comment: Also: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How do I configure CORS on the URL I'm redirected to? I can't find other solutions than the one I already tried.

Comment: If you cannot configure the server running at `http://localhost:7220` for CORS, you won't be able to consume its resources from the client side. You'll have to do so from your backend instead.

Comment: This is the applicationUrl from my launchSettings.json: `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7220;http://localhost:5220",`.
I think I definitely need to do it in the backend, but how can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this once on startup.cs file,

1. Create Global variable

   public string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
2. Inside ConfigureService function write

   services.AddCors(c =>
   {
   c.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, options =>
   options.AllowAnyOrigin()
   );
   });
3. then inside configure function, use below line.

   app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

Now run your app.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you using any authentication process like OPENID Connect or Cloud SSO, which require another auth server to provide a token to your request... In that case, you need to add your localhost link to that authserver( In organizations, who ever provided these parameters like ClientId, secrets, and redirect url...etc , you can ask them to add localhost weblink .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).